# Get amount of windows that are open from a process in Java

Tags: java, windows, process, window

Ok, so what I am trying to do is to make a program that automatically closes the second window that a process makes in Windows 10. By that I mean that a process can make a window, but as soon as it openes a second window, it closes the new window. The first step is to get the amount of windows open at the current time by a process. I guess that that cannot be done with just java, so if you know a library that can get the amount of windows opened by a process, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you'll need to provide more details-- especially what OS you're trying to do this on. Also, I don't understand why your second part. Why would you have to know how many windows are open by the process at startup? The 2nd window opened by the process would only be opened once in the process's lifetime.

Comment: @kwikness thank you for the suggestions for improvement, I'm doing this on windows 10, and I want to run the "amount of window detection" program on a loop, since the program is opening a new window every 10 minutes or so. The program is actually a trial version, which asks to buy a license, and I just want to write a program that closes that popup every time.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's a very unwieldy API, this would be best accomplished with using the Windows DWM: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/windowing

Give the documentation a good read-through and find/use the functions that will give you a count of open windows (which will always be associated with a parent window). There are quite a few ways to do this part-- use whatever works best for you out of [these functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/).

Once you get a handle on the window you're looking for, kill it with [`CloseWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-closewindow).